# What does the "one page per slab class" limitation mean when dumping keys with memdump?

Tags: memcached

For debugging purposes I want to count the number of keys in our memcache server, so I did some research and ended up using the [`memdump`](http://docs.libmemcached.org/bin/memdump.html) utility, which seems to come with libmemcached.

In the description of the command it says:

> memdump dumps a list of “keys” from all servers that it is told to fetch from. Because memcached does not guarentee to provide all keys it is not possible to get a complete “dump”.

Also on another website ([Memcached Cheat Sheet](http://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/memcached#Dumping%20Memcache%20Keys)) I read:

> […] The memcache protocol provides commands to peek into the data that is organized by slabs (categories of data of a given size range). There are some significant limitations though:
>
> 1. You can only dump keys per slab class (keys with roughly the same content size)
> 2. You can only dump one page per slab class (1MB of data)
> 3. This is an unofficial feature that might be removed anytime.
>
> […]

So what does `You can only dump one page per slab class (1MB of data)` mean in practice? One megabyte of data is what? If a slab contains more than 1 MB of data (including keys?) then the remaining data will not be fetched and i might miss some keys?

As an exmaple, I have 3 keys A with 500 KB of data, B with another 600 KB of data and C with 300 KB of data, they all go to the same slab. Then when dumping the keys, only A and B will be dumped with the data (which might then also be cut off?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memdump` utility employs memcache protocol undocumented command `stats cachedump` to obtain list of keys by slab id. You can look in `stats cachedump <slabs_id> <limit>` implementation in memcached source code [items.c](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/items.c):

```
char *item_cachedump(const unsigned int slabs_clsid, const unsigned int limit, unsigned int *bytes) {
        unsigned int memlimit = 2 * 1024 * 1024;   /* 2MB max response size */

    while (it != NULL && (limit == 0 || shown < limit)) {
    // ... key copying occurs here
    if (bufcurr + len + 6 > memlimit)  /* 6 is END\r\n\0 */
                break;
    // ...
    }
```

So it is impossible without recompiling memcached to get more than 2 Mb of keys per slab given. Values are not copied to response buffer, response size limit applies only to keys.

Comment: Ah so basically I can get 1 MB of keys?

Comment: @Max As you can see from memcached source code there is a hard 2MB limit on response buffer size for `cachedump` command. So, yes, you can get 1MB of keys.